# error in script (bash): ambiguous redirect

Tags: linux, bash, redirection

I'm rewriting a simple script, `CopyScript.sh`, I wrote a few years ago to copy contents from my NAS to a USB disk.

```
#!/bin/bash
SYNCPATH="/volume1/"
SYNCPATHTO="/volumeUSB1/usbshare/synology-may-2015-bak/"
NAMELOG="/volume1/homes/sando/logrsync.log"
echo "${NAMELOG}"
date >"${NAMELOG}"
rsync --verbose --recursive --size-only --exclude-from 'exclude-list.txt' $SYNCPATH $SYNCPATHTO >> $NAMELOG 2>&1
date  >> "${NAMELOG}"
echo DONE >> "${NAMELOG}"
```

However, when I execute `bash CopyScript.sh` I get the following error:
"ambiguous redirect: line 7: 1"

And indeed, when I look at the files in my filesystem, I see 2 logfiles called logrsync.log, one of 1 kB and one of 0 kB. I understand that this gives an ambiguous redirect, but why are there two files? I believe quite similar code worked on my old system. What am I missing?

Cheers,
Sando

Comment: You might be able to avoid all those `>>` lines with a simple `exec >"$NAMELOG"` before the first `date` (assuming your script ends there, and there's nothing following that's not to be logged).

Comment: You can't have two files with the same name in the same directory, so I suspect there are nonprinting/invisible characters involved. Try printing the script with `cat -vet CopyScript.sh` and see if that shows anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the NAMELOG variable inside quotes in the rsync redirection, ie "${NAMELOG}"

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid the error message does not change after adjusting the rsync redirection, however. I guess  the "1' in "7: 1" means the problem is in the line before `rsync`?

Comment: Line 7 is the rsync line I think. Try to comment that line out and run your script again.

Comment: @sand the "7:1" is a GNU convention meaning the line 7, column 1 (though the column is probably misleading in this case)

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to explain how it is a solution in this case.

Comment: @stathisv and Toby Speight: You are both right. I looked at the wrong line. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write the rsync activity in a logfile

But that is not to do this way with a redirect >> but via some parameters

```
--log-file=FILE         override the "log file" setting
--log-file-format=FMT   override the "log format" setting

**--log-file=FIL**E This option causes rsync to log what it is doing to a file.  This is similar to the logging that a daemon  does, but  can  be requested  for the client side and/or the server side of a non-daemon transfer.  If specified as a client option, transfer logging will be enabled with a default format of "%i %n%L".  See  the 
**--log-file-format** option if you wish to override this.

**--log-file-format=FORMAT** This  allows  you  to  specify  exactly what per-update logging is put into the file specified by the --log-file option (which must also be specified for this option to have any effect).   If  you  specify  an  empty  string, updated files will not be mentioned in the log file.  For a list of the possible escape characters, see the "log format" setting in the rsyncd.conf manpage. The default FORMAT used if --log-file is specified and this option is not is ’%i %n%L’.
```

So I whould try this:

```
rsync --verbose --recursive --size-only --exclude-from 'exclude-list.txt' --log-file=$NAMELOG  $SYNCPATH $SYNCPATHTO
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and will use it to my advantage. I believe the version of rsync I used on my previous NAS was ancient and lacked some of the parameters it now has. Still, I'd like to know why I'm getting the error and why there appear to be two logfiles with identical names.

Comment: two logfiles with identical names in the same folder? It's not possible to have two files with the same name. Though UNIX files are case sensitive, so it's entirely possible for filename, filenamE, and Filename to coexist in the same directory.